# My application includes #include<regex>. Does this work on XP machines?

Tags: c++, c++11, windows-xp

I have an application which supports  Windows version from XP. 
Recently I have made changes to the application by including `<regex>`.
Does this application still work in Windows XP machine?

P.S.: I did configure my application to use MFC in a static library.
If this doesn't work what should I install on XP machine to make this work?

Comment: If you target a platform you should have a way of testing deployment there. Asking on SO isn't a way to do that.

Comment: `<regex>` has nothing to do with MFC. It is standard C++11 and therefore you should find it in `msvcrt`, included in the redistributable package of Visual Studio ≥2010.